# How can I add Html tags (like <button>) in Popover Content (Bootstap) by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, popover

I am using Bootstrap-Popover. I want to have a button inside the popover. It was working fine earlier but now it's not working.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" id="pop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="">
  Button
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function updatePopover() {
    var popStr = "";
    popStr = popStr + "<h5> Heading :  </h5><div class='mx-2 my-2'>";
    popStr = popStr + "<button class='btn btn-success' onclick='function()' id ='funcid'>Button</button>"
    document.getElementById('pop').setAttribute('data-content', popStr);
    $('#popcart').popover('hide');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can do the following:

```js
var dynamicData = ['Dynamic Data', 'Dynamic Data', 'Dynamic Data', 'Dynamic Data'];

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    title: "<h5>Heading</h5>",
    content: function () {
        var resultData = $(`<div><ul class="list-group">`);
        for (var i in dynamicData) {
            resultData = resultData.add(
                `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    `+ dynamicData[i] + `
                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">`+ i + `</span>
                </li>`
            );
            // console.log(i, dynamicData[i]);
        }

        resultData = resultData.add(`</ul><br/><button class='btn btn-danger' id ='funcid'>Close</button></div>`);

        return resultData;
    }
});

$(document).on("click", "#funcid", function () {
    $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
});
```

```css
.popover-body {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">
    Button
</button>
```

Comment: Suppose I want to add some dynamic data in the popover. Like some data in a loop. How can I do it?

Comment: thanks for replying, I also wanted to know how can I list those dynamic data as bootstrap listing like - (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#with-badges)

Comment: Thank you soo much for helping me... I would really appreciate if you can help me with combining my dynamic data with your logic. I have mailed you my code at (s.pabon93@gmail.com). Please have a look!

Comment: Was there something added in newer versions of Bootstrap, that clear out input markup that is used inside a popover? For some reason the button elements (even tried input) gets removed from the markup. I've seen others complain of the same without resolution. I'm using Bootstrap version 4.3.1

Comment: Nvm, found the answer.. Have to add, "sanitize  : false"

Comment: Great @eaglei22

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is broken. You forgot `"` at the end of

```
popStr = popStr + "<button class='btn btn-success' onclick='function()' id ='funcid'>Button</button>"
```

Can you try that and check if it solves your problem.

Comment: I made mistake in copying. In original code i put "" but still it was not working